# Apache2.4 SetEnv to value of request header

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers, env

I want to set the value of env with a request header.

```
    SetEnv X_THING %{req:thing}
```

but it's not working as planned; it looks like the value of SetEnv isn't being evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so hard.
Basically, using the regex portion of SetEnvIf to extract the string, and use that to set the environment

```
    SetEnvIf thing ^(.*)$ X_THING=$1
```

Just be aware that anything put in there must be sanitised, since it comes from the remote request.